# Pugh exercise 1.18

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I am trying to solve the below exercise.

> Prove that real numbers correspond bijectively to decimal expansions to decimal expansions not terminating in an infinite string of nines, as follows. The decimal expansion of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is $N.x_1 x_2 \ldots$, where $N$ is the largest integer $\leq x$, $x_1$ is the largest integer $\leq 10(x-N)$, $x_2$ is the largest integer $\leq 100(x-(N+ x_1/10)$, and so on.

> (a) Show that each $x_k$ is a digit between $0$ and $9$.

> (b) Show that for each $k$ is there an $\ell \geq k$ such that $x_{\ell} \neq 9$.

> (c) Conversely, show that for each expansion $N.x_1 x_2 \ldots$ not terminating in an infinite string of nines, the set
> $$\{N, N + \frac{x_1}{10}, N + \frac{x_1}{10} + \frac{x_2}{100}, \ldots \}$$
> is bounded and its least upper bound is a real number $x$ with decimal expansion $N.x_1 x_2 \ldots$.

First, I'm having trouble understanding the construction. So $x = N.x_1 x_2 \ldots$. It makes sense to define $N = \lfloor{x} \rfloor$. I don't fully understand the digits $x_k$, though I know what they, intuitively, should represent.

I think part (a) can be done by induction on $k$, but the statement sounds as though it follows vacuously from the definition of the floor function. I tried to solve part (b) by contradiction, supposing that there exists a $k$ such that for all $\ell \geq k$, $x_{\ell} = 9$. Since $N \leq x$, $N - x \leq 0$, and
$$x = N.x_1 x_2 \ldots = N + \frac{x_1}{10} + \frac{x_2}{100} + \ldots,$$
we have
$$N - (N + \frac{x_1}{10} + \frac{x_2}{100} + \ldots) \leq 0.$$
By the assumption:
$$N - (N + \frac{x_1}{10} + \frac{x_2}{100} + \ldots + \frac{x_k}{10^k} + \frac{9}{10^{k+1}} + \frac{9}{10^{k+2}} + \ldots$$
I should be able to find a contradiction, but I can't figure out where to go from here.

For part (c): since each $x_k \leq 9$ by (a), we have
\begin{align*}
N + \frac{x_1}{10} + \frac{x_2}{10} + \ldots & \leq N + \frac{9}{10} + \frac{9}{100} + \ldots \\
& = N + 9 \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^k \\
& = N + 9 \cdot \frac{1}{9} \\
& = N + 1
\end{align*}
Non-emptyness seems vacuous: it's defined to be nonempty. So it has a supremum. I can't figure out how to proceed from here.

Any help on this problem would be appreciated. I will update this first post as I work on this problem more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will not be a complete solution, but it should help make clear what’s going on, give you a push in the right direction for finishing off all three parts.

To see how the digits $x_k$ are being calculated, imagine that we already knew that the decimal expansion of $x$ was $N.x_1x_2x_3\ldots\;$. Clearly $N=\lfloor x\rfloor$, and $x-N$ is the fractional part: $N-x=0.x_1x_2x_3\ldots\;$. Multiplying this by $10$ just shifts the decimal point one place to the right to yield $x_1.x_2x_3\ldots\,,$ and taking the floor picks off the digit $x_1$: $x_1=\lfloor 10(x-N)\rfloor$.

To get $x_2$, we need to apply the same idea to $0.0x_2x_3\ldots$: multiply it by $10^2$ to shift the decimal point immediately to the right of $x_2$, getting $x_2.x_3x_4\ldots\,,$ and take the floor. To do this, we have to have $0.0x_2x_3\ldots\,,$ so what is it? It’s $x-\left(N+\frac{x_1}{10}\right)$, so

$$x_2=\left\lfloor10^2\left(x-\left(N+\frac{x_1}{10}\right)\right)\right\rfloor\,.\tag{1}$$

In general, if we’ve determined $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, we have

$$N.x_1x_2\ldots x_n=N+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x_k}{10^k}\,,$$

and

$$x-\left(N+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x_k}{10^k}\right)=0.\underbrace{00\ldots00}_nx_{n+1}x_{n+2}\ldots\,,$$

so that we expect that

$$\begin{align*}
x_{n+1}&=\lfloor x_{n+1}.x_{n+2}x_{n+3}\ldots\rfloor\\
&=\left\lfloor 10^{n+1}\left(x-\left(N+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x_k}{10^k}\right)\right)\right\rfloor\,.
\end{align*}$$

Part (a) does require an argument: it is not vacuously true. Remember, we don’t actually have a decimal expansion: we’re showing that one exists. From the definition of the floor function we know that $0\le x-N<1$, so $0\le 10(x-N)<10$, and it follows immediately that $x_1$ is an integer, and $0\le x_1\le 9$.

We can now argue that $x_1\le 10(x-N)<x_1+1$, so $\frac{x_1}{10}\le x-N<\frac{x_1+1}{10}$, so

$$0\le x-\left(N+\frac{x_1}{10}\right)<\frac1{10}\,,$$

and therefore

$$0\le 10^2\left(x-\left(N+\frac{x_1}{10}\right)\right)<10\,.$$

It follows immediately that $x_2$, as defined by $(1)$, is an integer, and $0\le x_2\le 9$.

- Now see if you can use the step from $x_1$ to $x_2$ as a model for the general induction step from $x_n$ to $x_{n+1}$.

Your idea for (b) is basically sound. You will need to show by induction on $n$ that

$$x\ge N+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x_k}{10^k}$$

for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. You can then conclude that if $x_\ell=9$ for each $\ell\ge k$, then

$$\begin{align*}
x&\ge N+\color{red}{\sum_{\ell=1}^{k-1}\frac{x_\ell}{10^\ell}}+\sum_{\ell\ge k}\frac9{10^\ell}\\
&=N+\color{red}{\sum_{\ell=1}^{k-1}\frac{x_\ell}{10^\ell}}+\frac1{10^{k-1}}\,,
\end{align*}$$

where the red sum is $0$ if $k=1$. If $k=1$, this says that $x\ge N+1$, which we know is false, since $N=\lfloor x\rfloor$. If $k>1$, we can rewrite it as

$$x\ge N+\sum_{\ell=1}^{k-2}\frac{x_\ell}{10^\ell}+\frac{x_{k-1}+1}{10^{k-1}}$$

and show that this contradicts the definition of $x_{k-1}$ as

$$\left\lfloor 10^{k-1}\left(x-\left(N+\sum_{\ell=1}^{k-2}\frac{x_\ell}{10^\ell}\right)\right)\right\rfloor\,.$$

For (c) you should first be showing that $N$ and each of the numbers $N+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x_k}{10^k}$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ is bounded above by $N+1$; you should not yet be dealing with the infinite decimal. The calculation is almost identical to the one that you actually made: the only difference is the lefthand side. This shows that the set **has** a least upper bound. Let $y$ be that least upper bound; you’ll be done if you can show that $y$ has the decimal expansion $N.x_1x_2x_3\ldots\;.$

One approach is to show first that

$$N+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{x_k}{10^k}+\frac{x_n+1}{10^n}$$

is an upper bound for the set for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, so that for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ we have

$$N+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x_k}{10^k}\le y<N+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{x_k}{10^k}+\frac{x_n+1}{10^n}\,;$$

this follows from the definition of the digits $x_k$, and you can use it to show that the $x_k$ are the digits of the decimal expansion of $y$.